# What do we call a dynamic programic construct that allows us to compute sums of any range in logarithmic time?

Tags: sum, dynamic-programming, nomenclature

I was usually calling it ‘partial sums’, but I dunno how is it ‘officially’ called, and I have the impression it is not ‘partial sums’.

Anyway, the concept is pretty simple. Say you have an array of `8` elements, `[3, 7, 2, 1, 5, 6, 9, 4]`. You compute sums like that:

[image]

Of course, this will lead to an array of arrays of this form:

[image]

Now if we are asked, for example, what is the sum of elements of indexes from `0` till `4` we won’t linearily calculate that sum, but instead we will know it is equal to the sum of elements from `0` till `3` (which is `13`) and then logarithmically go down till the element `5`. So, the answer is: `18`.

How should I call such a construct so that other peaople know what I’m talking about without drawing tables like these?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some partitioning.

Storing cumulative sums allows calculation of sum of consecutive elements in constant time and takes same amount of memory (`n`).
Let i'th element of C be sum of all elements with with index <= i. Than sum of elements from index `a` till index `b` is `C[b] - C[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

Its called a **Segment Tree** and is usually used to *handle queries faster*.